# Is the data stored via Lawnchair in phonegap persistent after the app is closed?

Tags: cordova, lawnchair

I would like to use Lawnchair & Phonegap to create an android app.

Before I start, I'd like to know if the data saved via lawnchair is persistent after the app is closed?

E.g. I'd like the user to save a preference, close the app, and when they re-open the app, their preferences are remembered.

I don't need a code example ;-) just a yes/no/maybe would be great!

Thanks,
Lee

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is. Lawnchair is like PHP's PDO or Java's JDBC in that it abstracts the underlying data 'engine', allowing you to manipulate data from a host of different engines such as WebSQL, LocalStorage, Cookies, etc. Check the following link to view a list of supported engines: http://brian.io/lawnchair/adapters/

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you use `dom` or any available adapter which provides persistence capability.

[Lawnchair Adapters](http://brian.io/lawnchair/adapters/)